# Using Lists vs Agentsets

Tags: netlogo

Lists of agents and agentsets are two different data types in NetLogo (and can be converted with `turtle-set` and `sort`). The documentation states that you use lists for an ordered collection of agents and sets for an unordered collection. It appears that anonymous procedures available to lists makes lists more flexible than agentsets. On the other hand, using 'ask' in combination with agentsets is more common in the example models and has been stated to be more readable.

Can one translate any combination of list and anonymous procedure to a statement using an agentset and 'ask'? In particular, can you provide an equivelant of  `filter` or `map` using `ask` and agentsets? Please advise some situations in which one or the other is more appropriate, and the benefit that the structure provides.

Comment: this will almost certainly get closed as opinion based. But I almost never use lists of agents. The best use case for lists of agents I can think of is when an agent needs a memory, not just of which other agents it has interacted with, but in what order. On the other hand, I do use lists of values of some agent attribute. I suggest you write up an example of where you have used `filter` on an agent list and can't work out the equivalent `ask` and we can help with that. My best guess would be `with`.

Comment: I'm ready to concede that there might some measure of subjectivity when judging whether it's worth, e.g., converting a list to an agentset to take advantage of the nicer syntax, but I disagree that this question should be closed. There are objective technical differences between lists and agentsets that can be listed and explained. And (though maybe this last point *is* subjective) I think that understanding these differences and (more importantly) commonalities is a crucial part of understanding NetLogo. I gave a quick answer below, but I hope others can also chime in with even more insights.

Comment: Sorry Qualmy, this question should not have been closed.

Comment: I have edited. I think this will reopen it. I also removed some tags so that it is seen be NetLogo followers only. @Qualmy - I hope these edits are consistent with what you wanted.

Comment: Thank you! I tried to keep your edits that focus on observable statements and improved the formatting a bit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> you use lists for an ordered collection of agents and sets for an unordered collection. I feel there is more to it though.

Ordered vs. unordered is an important difference, but there is another crucial one: lists can contain duplicate items, agentsets cannot.

> I do not know how to properly implement an equivalent to `filter` or `map` using `ask`.

You don't need to implement those: they already exist!

The agentset version of `filter` is `with`:

```
my-agent-set with [ color = red ]
```

is the same as:

```
filter [ a -> [ color = red ] of a ] my-agent-list
```

The agentset version of `map` is `of`:

```
[ color ] of my-agent-set
```

is the same as:

```
map [ a -> [ color ] of a ] my-agent-list
```

And, as you may have intuited by now, `ask` is the equivalent of `foreach`.

Grasping these similarities is an important step towards NetLogo enlightenment. (Or even general programming enlightenment.)

The idea of unifying (or somehow generalizing) the syntax and primitives for these two types of collection has been discussed before (e.g., [here](https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/issues/594) and [here](https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/issues/1204)), but that kind of big language change tends not to happen very often.

> using agentsets (and 'ask') is more in line with the idea of Netlogo. It might be faster or easier to read.

As the code examples above nicely illustrate, agentsets do have a nicer syntax. And that's a good thing, since unordered collections of unique agents are usually what you need when doing agent-based modeling.

They're not inherently faster, though. Adding to them, in particular, is slower than adding to a list. To use a contrived example, it is much faster to do:

```
let my-list []
repeat 50 [ set my-list lput one-of turtles my-list ]
let my-agentset turtle-set my-list
```

Than to do:

```
let my-agentset no-turtles
repeat 50 [ set my-agentset (turtle-set my-agenset one-of turtles) ]
```

> What is your experience on this matter?

Agentsets are what's needed most of the time, but lists are also needed once in while.

Jen's example of using them for implementing a memory is a good one, but there are other use cases. Hopefully, you'll know them when you see them.